# Get-WMIObject: why does != NULL work with MACAddress but not IPAddress?

Tags: powershell, wmi

Can anyone tell me why this command works:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter "MACAddress != NULL"
```

whereas this one:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter "IPAddress != NULL"
```

produces:

```
Get-WmiObject : Invalid query "select * from Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration where IPAddress != NULL"
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter "IPAddress != NUL ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-WmiObject], ManagementException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMIManagementException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand
```

and what I should use, instead?

Answer (score 1):

MacAddress is a string, and IPAddress is a string Array.

[MSDN doc for Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394217%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Essentially, you'll just have to get all the adapters and parse whether the IPAddress is valid or not, since NULL and Empty are invalid queries.